# Validation @NotBlank does not work in connection with @JsonProperty

Tags: java, bean-validation, spring-annotations

I am trying to apply a `@NotBlank` validation to a class field. That field has also the `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("ID")
@NotBlank(message = "ID must not be blank")
private String id;
```

When I pass `""` or `" "` to the property and the incoming JSON field is named `"ID"` in capital letters then I do not see the expected constraint violation. If it is named `"id"` in lower case, then the JSON validation works properly.

However, in reality the JSON will come from the requester side in capital letters. So, I cannot simply remove `@JsonProperty`. Is there a way to solve this problem?